# Find highest value in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server database that currently shows data in below format

[image]

As you can see each project has different version number stored in database. What I want to do is to have the project with the latest version number and its related dates displayed in the reports. Hence I used the Row_Number and Partition by but somehow I'm not getting the result especially when I am putting my CTE and Partition Logic in Stored Procedure.

The data that I want is in below format;

[image]

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` should do the trick. Can you also post the query?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correlated subquery usually has good performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.version = (select MAX(t2.version) from t t2 where t2.projectname = t.projectname);
```

In particular, you want an index on `(projectname, version)` for optimal performance.

Comment: That query won't execute as-is (error "Subquery returned more than 1 value"). Shouldn't the subquery be `select MAX(t2.version) ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where version# = (select max(t1.version#) 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.projectname = t.projectname
                  );
```

However, you can also use `row_number()` function :

```
select top (1) with ties *
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by projectname order by version# desc);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT p.projectname, p.versionno,p.startdata,p.enddate 
FROM project p 
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT projectname, MAX(startdate) MaxDate 
FROM project GROUP BY projectname ) 
Dates ON p.projectname = Dates.projectname
 AND p.startdate = Dates.MaxDate
```

Comment: He want to latest  version no. of project so its depend on start date .

Comment: max(startdate) is latest date  so we can find version no. of project